# Scale up vs scale out

Tags: server

Which of these two server scaling options is more suitable? In first look, scale out would lead to network playing a bigger role, and hence related problems like latency etc coming in. So why should I go for scale out and not scale up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends on your use case.

Scaling up can be good in the short term, but scaling up is finite, i.e. if you can no longer buy a bigger machine, you will be stuck. Also, costs will go up exponentially with bigger machines.

Scaling out is "cheap" in terms of hardware but requires a little more thought (latency and consistency to name just a few). If done right, scaling out is effectively infinite.

Scaling up can sometimes also require downtime whereas scaling out does not have that issue.

So it all depends on your scaling needs. If you need to scale super fast (traffic spikes) scaling out is very interesting. If your traffic slowly grows but remains stable, you could start with scaling up, and convert to a scaling out strategy later on.

Comment: _costs will go up exponentially with bigger machines_ - Do you have a reference for this assertion,

Comment: It is not necessarily that machines will cost more relatively. Say if a single-core CPU costs X, it is not necessarily the case that the dual-core CPU will cost more than 2X (sometimes they do).

The problem rather is that for scaling up you typically are bound to the powers of 2. If your required capacity is 17 and your current provisioned capacity is 16, then you typically have to scale up to a capacity of 32, which is very costly compared to adding a single machine of capacity 1. That's what I meant with exponentially increasing cost.